# How to make "this" not refer to the element an event was called on?

Tags: javascript, events, this

*I know that there are no classes in Javascript, I refer to constructor functions as to classes for convenience.*

I'm making a class called `InputHandler` in Javascript. It has a method called `onMouseDown`, and it registers it as an event handler like this:

```
Irenic.InputHandler.prototype.attach = function()
{
    var inputHandler = this; //Get the instance of InputHandler

    document.addEventListener("keydown", inputHandler.onKeyDown, false); //Concentrate on this, but the question applies to all of these.
    document.addEventListener("keyup", inputHandler.onKeyUp, false);
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", inputHandler.onMouseMove, false);
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", inputHandler.onMouseUp, false);
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", inputHandler.onMouseDown, false);
}
```

(`Irenic` is the name of the engine I'm building, it is also a global object which has all these classes.)

The `inputHandler.onMouseDown` method looks like this:

Irenic.InputHandler.prototype.onMouseDown = function(event)
{
    var inputHandler = this; //This sadly refers to the document, not an instance of InputHandler

```
console.log(inputHandler); //Logs #document

if (event.button == 0)
{
    inputHandler.mouse.lmb = true;
}

if (event.button == 1)
{
    inputHandler.mouse.wheel = true;
}

if (event.button == 2)
{
    inputHandler.mouse.rmb = true;
}
```

}

As I've said in the comments, the `this` keyword refers to the element the event fired on. I obviously don't want that: **so how do I make it refer to an instance of `InputLoader`?**

Comment: Why not just use a closure, and this construct: (())()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your constructor, bind the instance's methods to that instance:

```
function InputHandler() {
    this.onKeyDown = this.onKeyDown.bind(this);
    this.onKeyUp = this.onKeyUp.bind(this);
    this.onMouseMove = this.onMouseMove.bind(this);
    this.onMouseUp = this.onMouseUp.bind(this);
    this.onMouseDown = this.onMouseDown.bind(this);
}
```

This way the instance is ready to go as soon as it is constructed.

See [`Function#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Answer (score 6):

Use [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to lock the context of a function:

```
inputHandler.onKeyDown.bind(inputHandler)
```

PS. use [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch), or at least `else if` instead of multiple `if` constructs. Only one of them can be true.

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but doesn't it have a lot of issues with IE?

Comment: @AdnanShammout addEventListener would have a lot of issues with IE anyway

Comment: @AdnanShammout IE does not support `addEventListener` prior v9. `.bind` is supported in all modern browsers, and MDN provides a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility) to support older browsers.

Comment: Yes, I can literally write this subset of bind from the top of my head in 3 seconds: `function bind(fn,ctx){ return function(){return fn.apply(ctx, arguments);}; }`

Answer (score 1):

I believe bind doesn't work with IE <= 8, so if this is required this should work:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function (ev) { return inputHandler.onKeyDown(ev); }, false)
```